# You uploaded an APK with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files

Tags: android, publish, publishing, godot, jar-signing

Here is a photo of my question when I upload a signed and aligned app to google play store.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CnaoTMjbtAgwDO9D9PDMwRqX-Ro3Aw64/view?usp=drivesdk

I am using godot 3.1.1
My app is signed and aligned but still i get this error.

For signing and aligning my app I used this link:
shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/

Comment: The link to the g drive asks for permissions. If possible, insert the text directly to you question. Also it is not clear what exactly you re asking / what have you tried.

Comment: Sorry....Here's the error I get when I upload my app to google developer console:UPLOAD ERROR   You uploaded an APK or android App bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of it's files. You need to create a valid signed APK or android App bundle.        This is the error.i used godot 3.1.1 to create my application  and used the above link to sign and align my APK..  PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score 0):

***Follow these steps -> It may be fix your problems***

**Step 1:** delete your build folder

**Step 2:** Check v1 & v2 signature when sign the apk

Now take build & upload the signed apk!!!